# UDM Pro VPN - Client can't reach LAN devices, but LAN devices can reach client

Tags: networking, vpn, ubiquiti

I'm setting up a home network with a Ubiquiti UDM Pro at the heart. I want to be able to remotely access the network over a VPN.

I followed [this article](https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005445768-UniFi-USG-UDM-Configuring-L2TP-Remote-Access-VPN) from Ubiquiti to set up the VPN gateway.

Using a Windows 10 PC, I was able to successfully connect to the VPN. From inside the LAN network, I am able to ping the VPN client, but my VPN client is not able to ping the LAN machines (yes, all the machines to have ping enabled). The client machine can ping the UDM Pro itself, and it can access the internet, but it cannot access the rest of the LAN.

Split-tunneling is *not* enabled (i.e. "Use default gateway on remote network" is checked), so I don't see how this could be a routing issue. All traffic should be going over the VPN.

From what I understand, the UDM Pro should allow the two networks (the LAN and the VPN) to talk to each other by default. I haven't set up any custom firewall rules that should interfere with this.

What's also interesting is that DNS resolution seems to be working. `PC-name.localdomain` resolves to the right IP address, but no packets get through.

What can I do to diagnose or resolve this problem? Let me know if there are any specific settings you ant me to check on either the Windows 10 client, or the Ubiquiti device.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. It was the Windows Firewall on the LAN device. It was configured to allow ping, but only originating from the local subnet. I had to add the VPN subnet to the allowed list, then it worked.

[image: Ping Firewall setting]